# How to use events in AngularJS Bootstrap Colorpicker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, color-picker

I can't figure out, how events work with [Angular Bootstrap Colorpicker](https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker). Here is a [Plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXbKRJ) I forked from the developer example. Sadly, the developer made no example for using events.

Events like `colorpicker-selected`, `colorpicker-selected-saturation`, `colorpicker-selected-hue`, `colorpicker-selected-alpha`, `colorpicker-shown`, `colorpicker-closed` should be supported. Just one example would be nice.

### Base code without any events:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('colorApp', ['colorpicker.module'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.nonInput = {
      color: ''
    };

    $scope.resetNonInputColor = function() {
      $scope.nonInput = {
        color: '#ffffff'
      };
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Looking at the source code, it seems like a simple `$scope.$on('colorpicker-shown', function(){ /* Your code goes here */ });` would work. (However, an `ngModel` has to be set up on the directive before it fires: https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-colorpicker-module.js#L528 )

Comment: Ohhh yea, its a `$rootScope` behavior. Please post this as answer, ill mark it as right. Thx m8. This plugin seems not to be compatible with angularJS directives. Its a kind of "random" handling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that you have an `ngModel` attached (which seems to be required, per the [source code](https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker/blob/21b20329e3346983efa08aa0d53275002cfbb6c5/js/bootstrap-colorpicker-module.js#L442)), you simply catch the emitted event with `$on` in an ancestor of the directive.

```
$scope.$on('colorpicker-shown', function(event, colorObject){
     console.log(colorObject);
});
```

All of the events that you asked about (`colorpicker-selected-alpha`, etc.) are available using their original names.